# print in the master page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, master-pages, vb.net-2010

I found in many websites a print button in every page

I think this where you can put it in the master page

I have tried `onclick="window.print"`
but it shows me error that window is not a part of something

could you please help me in doing this

"I Want a Print Button in Every Single Page In My Website "

Comment: Maybe you can post the exact error, so we can actualy try and help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have master page in all of your pages then you can put a button on master page.
And write javascript function as follows

```
<button onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
```

Here is a link

http://www.dotnettwitter.com/2011/02/how-to-print-content-page-information.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/387558/Javascript-Window-Print-not-working-in-Master-Page

### Edit 1

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="MessageButton" runat="server" 
                 OnClientClick="window.print();return false;"  ImageUrl="Header.gif"/>
```

Comment: but what if I want the button an imagebutton ?

Comment: use `OnClientClick="window.print();return false;"`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include parentheses:

```
<button onclick="window.print()">print</button>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/aD8yf/

Comment: Error 6 'print' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder'. C:\Documents and Settings\aalramil\Desktop\WebSite2+9\Site.master 167

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Master Page

```
<button value="print" onclick="window.print()"></button>
```